# Amazon S3 json files to BigQuery

Tags: json, amazon-s3, google-bigquery, ndjson

I want to transfer json files from Amazon S3 to BigQuery, but i've got the problem that BigQuery only support new delimited json files. I don't know how to transform my json files to ndjson. The problem is i dont know how to transform, because the load date and the record source within the outer JSON structure.

Here you can see an example of my json files:

```
{
    "edwLoadDate": "2017-01-18T18-08-44",
    "edwRecordSource": "MAILCHIMP",
    "data": [
        {
             "data": {
                  "lastName": "John",
                  "firstName": "Doe",
                  "email": "john@example123.com"
              },
            "edwSequence": "0"
          },  
          {
             "data": {
                  "lastName": "John",
                  "firstName": "Doe",
                  "email": "john@example123.com"
              },
            "edwSequence": "1"
           }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried transfering your sample JSON files to BigQuery with the following steps:

1. In your example JSON file, add a "[...]":

**input.json**

```
[{
    "edwLoadDate": "2017-01-18T18-08-44",
    "edwRecordSource": "MAILCHIMP",
    "data": [
        {
             "data": {
                  "lastName": "John",
                  "firstName": "Doe",
                  "email": "john@example123.com"
              },
            "edwSequence": "0"
          },  
          {
             "data": {
                  "lastName": "John",
                  "firstName": "Doe",
                  "email": "john@example123.com"
              },
            "edwSequence": "1"
           }
     ]
}]
```

2. Run a shell script command:

```
$ cat input.json | jq -c '.[]' > output.json
```

After running the shell script command, here's the **output.json** file:

```
{"edwLoadDate":"2017-01-18T18-08-44","edwRecordSource":"MAILCHIMP","data":[{"data":{"lastName":"John","firstName":"Doe","email":"john@example123.com"},"edwSequence":"0"},{"data":{"lastName":"John","firstName":"Doe","email":"john@example123.com"},"edwSequence":"1"}]}
```

3. Upload the converted JSON file to Cloud Storage buckets using the command:

```
gsutil cp output.json gs://sample-bucket
```

4. Create a sample BigQuery Dataset that will hold the uploaded BigQuery JSON file. Here's the result after querying:

[image]